# Using Linq to Sort Students within Groups and then Rearrange Group Order

Tags: c#, linq

I want to-

- Sort students in ascending order within each group (Example: Jack, John & Peter in Group 1, etc)
- Arrange all sorted groups in ascending order by their first item (Example: Group 3, 2 and 1)

**Collection**

```
public class StudentInfo
{
  public string Student { get; set; }
  public string University { get; set; }
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public bool IsQualified {get; set;}
}

List<StudentInfo> studentsList = new List<StudentInfo>();

StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="John", University="ABC", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=False});
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jack", University="DEF", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Peter", University="GHI", GroupID = 1, IsQualified=False} );

StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Olivia", University="ABC", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Donald", University="JKL", GroupID = 2, IsQualified=False} );

StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Adam", University="GHI", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=False} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jacob", University="ABC", GroupID = 3, IsQualified=False} );
```

**Expected Output**

```
Group 3:
Adam
Jacob

Group 2:
Donald
Olivia

Group 1:
Jack
John
Peter
```

**Pseudo Code**

```
var results = studentsList
 .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
 .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Student)).ToList();
```

I don't know what to write beyond this. Please help me.

Comment: do you want also sort student names inside each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update as per Krish comment**:

Arrange all sorted groups in ascending order by their first item

```
var results = StudentsList
    .OrderBy(x => x.Student)
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
    .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Student))
    .ToList();
```

**Update as per YoKidYo comment**

```
var results = StudentsList
     .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
     .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Student))
     .ToList();

foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.GroupID + " : " + item.Student);
}
```

> **result** :

```
3 : Adam
3 : Jacob
2 : Donal
2 : Olivi
1 : Jack
1 : John
1 : Peter
```

**Old code**

You can order by *descending* the `Keys`(groupId), and order by *ascending* student names inside each group, like the following code :

```
var results = StudentsList
     .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
     .Select(x => new { Group = "Group " + x.Key, Students = x.Select(y => y.Student).OrderBy(z => z).ToList() })
     .ToList();
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: Don't know why they give down vote for this.. your query is good except a small flaw in logic based on the given question. order by based first element of the sub group. For eg. if you swap 2 and 3 groupid it should display in order Group 2,3,1

Comment: @Sajid, is it possible to update the original collection instead of iterating? Thanks.

Comment: can you check my update, if understand correctly, you want at the first time to order by group id, and in the second by student names?

Comment: @YoKidYo, i see a comment here ;), then i'am adding loop and result in the updated code

Comment: Don't mind... There was a mistake from my side and your code had no issues.

Comment: @YoKidYo But this is **not** the **correct answer** for this question!

Comment: @FarhadZamani First of all, I thank you for answering. As I tested the previous edit of Sajid (not sure about last edit), it worked! Hence marked.

Comment: @YoKidYo You're welcome. glad I helped you, but I updated the answer sooner and it's not fair. good luck :]

Comment: @Sajid still the flaw exists.. The query work for the given example not for all scenario.   please switch the groupid and see whether it satisfies the condition, based on second point in the question..

Comment: @Sajid  var results = StudentsList
   .OrderBy(x => x.Student)
   .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID)   
   .Select(x => new { Group = "Group " + x.Key, Students = x.Select(y => y.Student).OrderBy(z => z).ToList() })
   .ToList();

Comment: @Krish why you use Group by twice?

Comment: he wants to order students inside each group and ordering by group ids, can you put an example?

Comment: yes. but ordering group ids based on first item of each group

Comment: For eg. if I trade 2 and 3 groupid as per the given list it should display as follows Group 2:
Adam,Jacob
Group 3:
Donald,Olivia
Group 1:
Jack,John,Peter

Comment: @Krish, it's updated, i understand. i ordered by ``keys`` , but will ordered by student first after grouping. Thank you very mush..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209853/discussion-between-krish-and-sajid).

Answer (score 1):

So the Linq query has sorted the data for you but now you need to display it. I have tested and it displays your expected output. Code below:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<StudentInfo> studentsList = new List<StudentInfo>();

        studentsList.Add(new StudentInfo { Student = "John", University = "ABC", GroupID = 1, IsQualified = false });
        studentsList.Add(new StudentInfo { Student = "Jack", University = "DEF", GroupID = 1, IsQualified = false });
        studentsList.Add(new StudentInfo { Student = "Peter", University = "GHI", GroupID = 1, IsQualified = false });
        studentsList.Add(new StudentInfo { Student = "Olivia", University = "ABC", GroupID = 2, IsQualified = false });
        studentsList.Add(new StudentInfo { Student = "Donald", University = "JKL", GroupID = 2, IsQualified = false });
        studentsList.Add(new StudentInfo { Student = "Adam", University = "GHI", GroupID = 3, IsQualified = false });
        studentsList.Add(new StudentInfo { Student = "Jacob", University = "ABC", GroupID = 3, IsQualified = false });

        var results = studentsList.OrderBy(x => x.Student)
            .GroupBy(x => x.GroupID);


        foreach (var group in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Key);

            foreach (var student in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(student.Student);

            }

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

public class StudentInfo
{
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public string University { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public bool IsQualified { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
 var groupedStudents = studentsList.GroupBy(a => a.GroupID, (key, Students) => new
 {
     Key = key,
     StudentsList = Students.ToList()
 }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Key).ToList();
 foreach (var item in groupedStudents)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Group " + item.Key + ":");
     foreach (var stdList in item.StudentsList.OrderBy(a => a.Student))
     {
         Console.WriteLine(stdList.Student);
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
 }
```

Output:

```
Group 3:
Adam
Jacob

Group 2:
Donald
Olivia

Group 1:
Jack
John
Peter
```

Comment: you miss to order students by name here